# Logic query - jquery mobile - multi page templates

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Why do multi-page templates exist?

I can find no information which suggests a faster page load or any other reason for them to exist.

A bigger page obviously takes the first page longer to load but is the speed saved while moving to another page within that page that great? As transitions will be the same as you set for all the pages.

Am I missing something in the docs or in page loading logic?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small website where you know the scale of its size then it can be useful to load the whole site at once **which will reduce server requests** (which on mobile devices introduces a lot of latency overhead, here is a good article on this subject: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2011/09/21/making-a-mobile-connection/).

Loading all the pages at once allows transitions to happen smoothly without a loading message. Because of the nature of mobile websites (being viewed on mobile devices) the user may lose reception and be shown the loading message for a long time (which people generally dislike, however I have seen some entertaining loading animations).

A clear disadvantage of loading all the pages at once is that if your user does not navigate to one or some of those pages then that's wasted bandwidth. Images are a good example of this, when I create a small mobile website I use a multi-page template and I lazy-load the images when a user actually navigates to the page where that image exists.